# How to use CPLEX or GUROBI in PySCIPOpt (Scip in Python)

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, gurobi, scip

I have been working with SCIP in python using PySCIPOpt. 
I could see SCIP also works with CPLEX and Gurobi engines, does anyone know how to use it in PySCIPOpt?

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is probably to ask on the SCIP mailing list mentioned [here](https://scip.zib.de/index.php#contact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt) needs a suitable SCIP library, so all you need to do is compiling/linking SCIP with the LP solver of your choice.

You should check the [documentation for details](https://scip.zib.de/doc-7.0.0/html/CMAKE.php#CMAKE_CONFIG) on how to do this. Generally, it should be as easy as

```
cmake -Bbuild -H. -DLPS=grb -DGUROBI_DIR=/path/to/gurobi
cmake --build build
```