# How to use PySCIPOpt with gurobi solver?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, scip, pyscipopt

I use SCIP because it has nice branching tools like handler, but the solver is not as fast as I would like. I got access to gurobi (and maybe cplex) because I know they can work together, but have no idea.

Disclaimer: I have use cmake and install pyscipopt trough conda.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just edited it. Sorry. The sleepiness bet me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CPLEX or GUROBI in PySCIPOpt (Scip in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186016/how-to-use-cplex-or-gurobi-in-pyscipopt-scip-in-python)

Comment: I read that, but don't understand how to do that. Don't know where to do it and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PySCIPOpt with Gurobi (or any other LP solver or custom SCIP build) if you are using the conda installation package. This package already includes a pre-built SCIP.

To customize your setup, you need to build SCIP yourself and then build PySCIPOpt by pointing to this SCIP build via the `SCIPOPTDIR` environment variable as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186016/how-to-use-cplex-or-gurobi-in-pyscipopt-scip-in-python). Please refer to the [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md) file for detailed instructions on how to link PySCIPOpt to an existing SCIP build.